# Moving control to Native app from UI Web View in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

Is there any mechanism for **Moving control to Native app from UI Web View in IOS** applications? I want to avoid the apples 30% tax in purchasing through native app. I am trying to load web url in UI WebView controller for purchasing but can't get last response through which I can move back to app from UI WebView and display thank you message.
Any Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sort of in-app purchases will not be approved by apple.

Comment: @PraveenS:then is there any other way to avoid this?

Comment: If you want to sell anything app-related in your app you pay Apple 30% or your App will not be approved for sale in the AppStore at all